# how to share link from my app to signal, bottom, email web and app?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send/?text=http://somesite/reception/mypage 
   target="_blank" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"  data-original-title="whatsapp">
   whatsapp
</a>
```

how can i share something means text or url or audio or video from my rails application's simple html anchor tag to signal app. for whatsapp share , i used like below. Is there any kind of link?

Answer (score 2):

Signal has enabled this since last year:

```
https://signal.me/#p/+<phone with country code>
```

or

```
sgnl://signal.me/#p/+<phone with country code>
```

e.g.,

```
<a href="https://signal.me/#p/+11234567890" target="_blank">
```

Sources:
[Link 1](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/commit/3cc2cd0b17847f548f20a97c9c9f91cb07b08d04)
[Link 2](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/commit/0685cf4e515bc0d0c625f32e9194ab17913b2a00)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, but your href is missing closing quotes, which could be the problem

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send/?text=http://somesite/reception/mypage"
   target="_blank" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"  data-original-title="whatsapp">
   whatsapp
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. I got a solution for sharing link to whatsapp, linkedin, twitter, facebook ;like above . But I didn't get solution to share link to botim, signal and telegram. this is my actual question. Please answer if u know the solution . thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

For telegram you can use something like this :

```
<a href="https://telegram.me/share/?url=someurl&text=sometext">Share</a>
```

hit me up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075075/share-via-signal-messenger-html-href-link) if you find the solution for signal

Comment: thanq for ur answer and u gave for url , text params. is there any parameter to send particular contact number from telegram

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to share a link in Signal. Your question about it seems to have been removed. Did you find a solution? Could you update the link to your question?